# Force to create admin user, if root was locked

Tags: centos, kickstart

I've created a kickstart file for automated installation of CentOS 7. Idea is to make foolproof oem installation, so root is locked, user have to be created on final part of installation. But here is a problem - user can be created without sudo priveleges, or can be not created at all - anaconda installer OK with that. But I noticed, what if you did't agreed with EULA - it won't pass you any further. Am I missing any kickstart option, what allows that behaviour, or I need to customize Anaconda Installer?

Answer (score 0):

You could agree with EULA using kickstart using `eula` option, more you could [read in official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax).

> `eula` (optional)
> Use this option to accept the End User License Agreement (EULA) without user interaction. Specifying this option prevents Initial
> Setup from prompting you to accept the license agreement after you
> finish the installation and reboot the system for the first time. See
> Chapter 30, Initial Setup for more information.
>
> `--agreed (required)` - Accept the EULA. This option must always be used, otherwise the eula command is meaningless.

Comment: Well, yeah. But problem not in eula agreement. Problem in user creation. So, i dig some python code of Anaconda installer, and found how to make user creation mandatory. But here is a trick. It applies on installation itself, not on first boot. So, if i make it mandatory, it stops kickstart installation until you create an user.
After that, I realized, what eula agreement screen is in Initial-setup package, which starts after first reboot. But in python scripts it contains I didn't find how to make user creation mandatory. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something